# npm config permission error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am having permission problems with the `npm config` command. It seems that for some reason it is trying to change the owner of my `~/.npmrc` file. When running `npm config set color false`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chown '/home/bamboo/.npmrc'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, chown '/home/bamboo/.npmrc'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path: '/home/bamboo/.npmrc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "config" "set" "color" "false"
npm ERR! cwd /home/bamboo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/bamboo/.npmrc
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, chown '/home/bamboo/.npmrc'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bamboo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

The file `.npmrc` has the right permissions and I can edit it manually but I need to do it from the `npm config` command since it is part of an automated build. I can't seem to find valuable information on that matter. I set the `prefix` to a directory I own and can install globally without any problem but can't run configure! I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Does anybody have some ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo npm config set color false`?

Comment: @pstenstrm Of course I did and it works. The point is that I cannot run as `sudo` during the automated build process. I also never had this problem before on other systems.

Comment: They have a [great video](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) about npm permissions. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros this video is about global installation permission issues, this works fine for me.

Comment: What is the owner:group and permissions of `/home/bamboo/.npmrc`? I assume the automated build is being run as `bamboo`?

Comment: Also, how did you install node/npm? On a clean VM `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs && sudo apt-get install npm && npm config set color false` works fine for me.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple As you expect, the build is run as `bamboo` and owner:group are `bamboo:bamboo`. `nodejs` was installed using `apt-get`, but using the chris-lea ppa. I will try re-installing node and see how it goes. Thanks for taking the time to test in a VM!

Comment: @mor Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @qqilihq As suggested by @TimothyStrimple I reinstalled npm and nodejs, but this time without the `ppa:chris-lea/node.js` and it now works. The version of npm is now `1.3.10` and working. I don't really have time to dig deeper into that but version `1.4.28` was problematic for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7563

Turns out changing from  `sudo su` to `sudo su -` when starting the bamboo agent process solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem once.

The .npm directory does not have sufficient permissions. Run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```